# How to get rid of Iron Router splash page

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have a Meteor app and I'm using the iron:router package. Both when I deploy to meteor.com and when I'm developing locally, an iron router splash page shows up on the page with the line "Organize your meteor application". How can I get rid of this? I've tried a number of things but nothing seems to have helped.

Thanks

Comment: You need to add a route. Follow the instructions on the splash screen or remove iron router using `meteor remove iron:router`

Comment: I've made a route on the server in a js file. Is it possible that iron router isn't picking up where it is?

Comment: You need a route on the client too. Iron router is trying to find something to route for `/`. It can't find anything so it displays this notice.

Comment: I think that was the problem. I added a route to a global js file and it no longer shows up.

Answer (score 2):

Iron Router runs on both the client and the server, so make sure the route is defined in both places, i.e. some not under `/client` or `/server` folders. See [docs](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#client-and-server).

Answer (score 1):

There is an option which allows you to provide your own "not found" template:

```
Router.configure({
    notFoundTemplate: "notFound"
});
```

The default not found template is called `__IronRouterNoRoutes__`
See

- https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=notFoundTemplate
- [https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=**IronRouterNoRoutes**](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=__IronRouterNoRoutes__)

Comment: And I created a html file with a template named `notFound` with no contents